# Google Sheets Stuck On "Working" and Formulas working strangely

Tags: macos, google-sheets, safari, browser-support

Any sheet I open keeps showing the "Working" green notification at the top of the window, and the cells don't autopopulate when I start typing a formula. I.e. when I start typing "=ifer" it shoud automatically show the "iferror" option. However, the formual works once I fully type it.

This is happening in Safari. I already tried to restart my mac in safe mod and then restart normally, reboot it normally, clean history, reload the page several times, but no luck. It's been going on for days now.

OS: OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Have you ever seen this?

Comment: You can go to `Help` > `Help Sheets improve`. It will allow to send feedback about this, including a description, a screenshot, the browser information, etc.

Comment: Does that really work? I've tried it a couple of times and never got an answer

Comment: Suffering this on a mac at the moment - looking to possibly be a side effect of planned obsolescence on Macs. Hope to come back with a solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

Client had been having this exact issue for the past week, and in finding a solution in the past hour, I hope this helps you.

They were also on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6, and though I've tried to clear the working error in Safari unsuccessfully, the computer in question was doing the same on Chrome, and the following solution worked to access the spreadsheet correctly again on Chrome.

In Chrome:

- Step 1: Tap the Chrome menu icon and select Settings.
- Step 2: Scroll to the 'Privacy and security section' and select 'Clear browsing data.'
- Step 3: Go to the Advanced tab and check only the 'Hosted app data' box. Finally, tap the Clear data button to proceed.

Various tips are outlined at https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-google-sheets-not-loading-chrome/ if the above doesn't work for you. The above solution which worked for me was option 2 on that page.